# Change arrangement of iPad used as Sidecar Display

Tags: macos, ipad, display, catalina, sidecar

I have an iPad Pro (2018 3rd Gen) that I'm using as 2nd display with my Macbook Pro (2018).  I can enable it and it works well, but it's on the wrong side of my Macbook and there's no options in Sidecar to change the display arrangement.

***How do I change the monitor arrangement of my iPad relative to my Macbook?***

Answer (score 1):

Sidecar has no settings to change monitor arrangement. You only enable the iPad as an additional display in the Mac's ***System Preferences***.  You still have to go to "***Displays***" in your Mac's System Prefs to change the arrangement of the iPad as a display relative to your Mac.

After (2) days of dragging things in the opposite direction to the iPad display it finally occurred to me to check ***Displays***...  *D'Oh!*